# Does std::set store objects contiguously in memory?

Tags: c++, set, stdset

Does `std::set` store objects in contiguous memory like `std::vector`?

I haven't been able to find this on the web, cppreference doesn't mention details on memory allocation. But I can't see why it couldn't use contiguous memory, hence my question.

Comment: Read `set::insert` requirements : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert  _"...No iterators or references are invalidated...."_ so it can't reallocate when it needs to expand like a `std::vector` does.

Comment: Performance: you need to measure (depends on your hashing function)for your use-case see: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-661 from __45:48__

Comment: See also [boost::flat_set](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx).

Comment: Do you mean 'contiguous' as in "as the set is iterated, objects are stored in contiguous memory locations", or as in "all the objects are stored in one big chunk of memory (but in arbitrary order)"?

Comment: @PabloH I mean, just like std::vector.

Comment: Generally, when you find yourself asking "is container A the same as container B", the answer is "no", otherwise there would only be container A (because what would be the purpose in having container B?). This doesn't apply to container _adaptors_ of course, but `std::set` is not one of those things, which is the key here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0 I see what you mean. Not sure if my question is equivalent to "is A the same as B?" though.

Comment: @mfnx granted it's 50% ;)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Does std::set store objects in contiguous memory like std::vector?

There is no guarantee that it does. Also in practice, it cannot because of the requirements of the container. Therefore no, it does not store objects in contiguous memory.

> I can't see why it couldn't use contiguous memory

References to elements of the set must remain valid upon insertion to it as well as erasure (except for references to the erased element). This requirement is incompatible with contiguous memory.

As far as I know, a balanced search tree is the only data structure that can implement `std::set`.

Comment: It could carve space for tree nodes out of large contiguous chunks, in case that's what the OP meant.  (But no iterator invalidation rules out `insert` copying all the nodes into a new larger block to limit it to only *one* block, in case in-place realloc fails or (typical for C++) the allocator doesn't support such a realloc.)

Answer (score 15):

It isnt excluded explicitly, though certain constraints for `std::set` make it impossible to use contiguous memory.

For example, `set::insert` has logarithmic complexity while `vector::insert` requires linear complexity to shuffle its entries. Also `set::insert` does not invalidate iterators. Both requirements cannot be realized with continguous memory.